# Error building 0.9.1 release of red5

Tags: red5

I'm trying to build the 0.9.1 release of red5.
I checked out

```
svn co http://red5.googlecode.com/svn/java/server/tags/0_9_1
cd 0_9_1
ant
```

But I receive the folloing error.

```
[ivy:resolve]           ::          UNRESOLVED DEPENDENCIES         ::
[ivy:resolve]           ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
[ivy:resolve]           :: commons#commons-modeler;2.0.1: not found
[ivy:resolve]           :: commons#commons-httpclient;3.1: not found
[ivy:resolve]           :: red5#xmlrpc;2.0.1: not found
[ivy:resolve]           ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
[ivy:resolve]
```

How to solve this error ?

Thank you a lot for any help,

Answer (score 0):

Update the ivy.xml to reflect changes in the dependencies. Here is where you can find the first one and search for the others:

http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/commons-modeler/commons-modeler/2.0.1

Click on the ivy tab.